# Editing RAM in real time

Tags: memory, forensics

Is it possible to edit ram in real time with hexdump or any other program? 
How?

I read here http://linuxpoison.blogspot.pt/2011/04/how-to-read-content-from-ram-random.html that I can see the contents of the ram, but doesn't explain how to edit them or whether if that's possible